# Statsforecast for python seems to predict values "one day ahead"

Tags: python, time-series, statsforecast

I have been trying Statsforecast for Python now for a couple of weeks. It seems really good, however I noticed that my predictions always feels a bit off by one day. If you look at the first image, you can see how the graph almost matches with a difference of a day. If I displace the values one day, you can see that the graphs matches much better, however I lose the last day, 31st on this case.

I feel like I am missing something when I am training the model. Has anyone experienced this?

[image: initial predictions]

[image: predictions displaced by -1]